# How to convert native C++ memory into C# structure?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I have the following native function interface in C++:

```
int func1(void* param, int sizeOfParam).
```

In documentation the following example of call is provided:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
} Rect;

Rect rect;

int func1((void*)&rect, sizeof(rect));
```

I need to call this function from C# code.

I have the following header in C# from developers of native library:

```
[DllImport(NATIVE_DLL_NAME, 
 CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
 EntryPoint = "func1")]
private static extern int func1(IntPtr param, int sizeOfParam);
```

I also have the following C# structure `Rect`:

```
public struct Rect
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

I need to call `func1` in C# code and pass `Rect`:

I do the following:

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
int rectSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(rect);

func1(???, rectSize);
```

What to place in position of `???` where `rect` should be passed (but it is not possible because of incompatible types)?

It seems that `IntPtr` should be passed and then converted to `struct rect`. How to achieve this?

(`rect` is output parameter here)

**UPDATE:**

It is desired not to change signatures of C++ code and C# wrappers - it is third part code.
Moreover it is not always variable of `Rect` is passed as first param of `func1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changed the rules of the game to disallow modifications to the C# code. And so the P/invoke must be of this form:

```
private static extern int func1(IntPtr param, int sizeOfParam);
```

In that case you need to do the marshalling by hand:

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Rect));
IntPtr param1 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
try
{
    func1(param1, size);
    Rect rect = (Rect)Marshal.PtrToStructure(param1, typeof(Rect));
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(param1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for confusion. Just small question. Can absence of `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` in Rect potentially cause the issues?

Comment: You do need to use `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`. And what issues are you seeing?

Comment: No issues for now. Thanks. I just read at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t2cwe11%28v=vs.71%29.aspx definition of StructLayout and was afraid that compiler can rearrange members of struct as it likes. And if now it is not an issue it does not mean that in future it will not appear.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably make life a bit easier for yourself by using an `out` param of type `Rect` rather than `IntPtr`.  Like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rect
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};

[DllImport(NATIVE_DLL_NAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "func1")]
private static extern int func1(out Rect param, int sizeOfParam);
```

Then to call the function you can write this:

```
Rect param;
int res = func1(out param, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Rect)));
```

Comment: Yeah, you really made life easier :) Strange thing that it is not always `Rect` is passed as a first param...

Comment: You can create `func1Rect`, `func1SomeOtherType` etc. to deal with that.

Comment: no, can't. I updated question to make things clearer: C++ code and C# wrappers are third party and I would like not to modify them. Of course, if no other solutions exist, I should update them indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing ref Rect instead.

```
[DllImport(NATIVE_DLL_NAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "func1")]
private static extern int func1(ref Rect param, int sizeOfParam);
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I am asking about. I clarified question.